# SVG does not show up in html

Tags: html, svg

I have made a simple design in inkscape and want to use it in a website but when I add it using an image tag it does not show up. If a add an alt to the img tag then only the text in the alt tag shows up

My code:

```
<img src="/svg/logo.svg" alt="logo">
```

I have tried [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/serve-svg-correct-content-type/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20trying%20to,with%20an%20incorrect%20content%2Dtype.) solution from css-tricks.com but the issue still persists. I have also tried saving it as an optimized svg in inkscape but that does not work either.

Edit 1: For anyone wondering I am using the new edge
Edit 2:
[image: My files jst incase that they are important]

Comment: Open the network tab in your browser's developer tools. Check the request is returning the image and not, for example, a 404 error.

Comment: Don't see anything of importance there. There is just my style.css file under the Name section

Comment: If there isn't even a *request* for the SVG then something has gone very wrong.

Comment: [This is what I see](https://imgur.com/a/ml8KF2G)

Comment: Is logo.svg actually saved at /svg/logo.svg? That `/` could either be your machine's root dir or your working directory. Have you tried `svg/logo.svg` (no leading slash)?

Comment: Just tried it. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I was using the logo template inkscape which do not work. If you are facing the same problem trying not using a template.

Answer (score 0):

With your folder structure I would say that this is the right path:

`<img src="../svg/logo.svg" alt="logo">`

You need to go out of the src folder first with `../`